# Return Null in Reset Password in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, null, nullreferenceexception, forgot-password, reset-password

I have a function for forget and reset password.
forgot password works correct and send email correctly and return Email Active code too.
but why for reset always returns null ?

RessetPassword function:

```
    [Route("ResetPassword")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ResetPassword()
    {
        
        return View();
    }

    [Route("ResetPassword")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel reset)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            
        {
            var result = await _userService.ResetPassword(reset);

            switch (result)
            {
              ....... 
                    break;
            }
        }

        return View(reset);
    }
```

but always return null just active code email, password and re password goes correctly frim view:

```
@model AryanITC.Domain.ViewModels.Account.ResetPasswordViewModel
```

```
        <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" type="password" class="pass >
        <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="field-validation-valid col-md-12 text-danger"></span>

        <button type="submit" class="submit text-center"> submit </button>
       
    </form>
</div>
```

as i said this link return after forgot password :

```
https://localhost:44385/resetpassword?EmailActiveCode=0e08ae5f498d4485a7d0ccc265ebfa1a
```

but from view , EmailactiveCode returns NULL???

this is my view model:

```
public class ResetPasswordViewModel
{ 
    public string EmailActiveCode { get; set; }


    public string Password { get; set; }


    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as i said this link return after forgot password :
>
> ```
> https://localhost:44385/resetpassword?EmailActiveCode=0e08ae5f498d4485a7d0ccc265ebfa1a
> ```

When using the above request URL to access the ResetPassword endpoint, it will go to the ResetPassword Get method first, so, in the ResetPassword Get method, you can add a parameter to receive the EmailActiveCode, and then return a view model to the ResetPasswrod page, code like this:

```
    [Route("ResetPassword")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ResetPassword(string EmailActiveCode)
    {
        var reset = new ResetPasswordViewModel();
        reset.EmailActiveCode = EmailActiveCode;
        return View(reset);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so so much , it works. I have a few problem to get some entrance in methods and now I get it. Thanks so much.